# JavaDoc is missing in Maven Jar

Tags: maven, jar, javadoc

I added JavaDoc content for my method. After the maven build, the JavaDoc contents are removed from the jar file. How to prevent removing the JavaDoc content from the class file during maven build?

Answer (score 2):

That is by design. Class files do not contain JavaDoc. Therefore the normal `jar` files distributed of a library don't contain JavaDoc either.

If you want to download the JavaDoc, either get the source jar file or download the JavaDoc manually.

In IDEs the common approach is to download source jars.

You can even make Maven [produce a JavaDoc artifact](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) in addition of your normal jar.

Comment: I want to convert my project as a jar file. At the build time, JavaDoc contents are removed from my project. Can you please tell, Is there any way to exclude the JavaDoc remove process from my project.

Comment: @SteveRogers: there **is no "JavaDoc remove process"**! Class files inherently don't contain JavaDoc. You can make Maven create a `-javadoc` artifact that users can download if you want to avoid distributing the source.